# Xcode 10.1 fails to compile after Catalina update

Tags: xcode, build, macos-catalina

I have recently updated to Catalina (10.15), and I am still using Xcode 10.1, as my project requires it.

However, every time when I just Build the project I get errors like:

```
error: unexpected service error: build aborted due to an internal error: No space left on device (28)
```

or

```
fatal error: error in backend: IO failure on output stream: No space left on device
Command CompileC failed with a nonzero exit code
```

or sometimes it just freezes, and I have to force quit it.

I tried with a clean build, restating, deleting derived data, creating a new project from scratch, but I still face this issues.

Also, it's not just Xcode that misbehaves, also Skype and other apps seems to hang and not deliver messages.

It's strange to think that I'm the only one experience this issue, since I don't have any special configuration, other than a slightly older Xcode.

Comment: Try to ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com, as it looks more like an issue with your disk space or with your version of Catalina. Kind reminder that Xcode 11 will become mandatory for AppStore [April 2020](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/), so you better hurry converting this Swift 3 code to a newer version.